# How to restart anacron every hour?

Tags: cron, crontab

What is the proper way to restart anacron? I want to set it up to restart every hour. Would a crontab entry like do the job?

```
sudo crontab -e
@hourly anacron
```

Why is anacron initially started by default from in the `/etc/crontab` and not in the `sudo crontab`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anacron doesn't run as a daemon, it's run from `/etc/cron.d/anacron`. It's there to handle longer time frames, not hourly events. The regular cron takes care of those.

If you want something to happen every hour, dump it in `/etc/cron.hourly/`, or schedule it via your `crontab`.

It's not started from root's crontab, because that's a single file, hidden in `/var/spool`, rather than a `.d` directory in `/etc`